# Quickly reference static methods

Tags: c#, class, methods, reference, shortcut

Is it by any chance possible to call a method without referencing to its class?

For instance, you have a helper class:

```
class HelperTools
{
    public static void DoWork()
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

And then you need to call it:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HelperTools.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call `DoWork();` without a reference? Like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    DoWork();
}
```

Just for sake of simplicity.

Comment: Why? What is the practical use of this? Serious question, I'm curious.

Comment: There are some ways to do that, (e.g. private method that calls static method, make it `class MainClass : HelperTools`, dynamic invokations) but it would be very counter-intuitive for anyone familiar with how things are normally done in C#. The ordinary C# way is to simply call `HelperTools.DoWork();` or, for extension methods, `myObj.MyExtensionMethod()`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Simplicity. Notice the "shortcut" tag - I'm just looking for quicker ways to call a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite, but here are 5 patterns that get you close:

```
namespace My.Namespace
{
    using H = MyHelperClass;

    public class MyHelperClass
    {
        public static void HelperFunc1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here's your help!");
        }
    }

    public class MyHelperClass2
    {
        public static void HelperFunc4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here's your help!");
        }
    }

    public interface IHelper{ }

    public static class HelperExtensions
    {
        public static void HelperFunc3(this IHelper self)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here's your help!");
        }
    }

    public class MyClass : MyHelperClass2, IHelper
    {
        private static readonly Action HelperFunc2 = MyHelperClass.HelperFunc1;

        private static void HelperFunc5() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here's your help!");
        }

        public void MyFunction()
        {
            //Method 1 use an alias to make your helper class name shorter
            H.HelperFunc1();
            //Method 2 use a class property
            HelperFunc2();
            //Method 3 extend an interface that has extension methods.
            //Note: you'll have to use the this keyword when calling extension
            this.HelperFunc3();
            //Method 4 you have access to methods on classes that you extend.
            HelperFunc4();
            //Method 5 put the helper method in your class
            HelperFunc5();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No.  Java has the concept of importing static like this, but C# does not.  (IMO, a naked `DoWork()` without any clue as to where the implementation resides is non-ideal.)

Comment: Yes it is ideal. Time is money and not all classes are complex and full of horde of class usages.

Answer (score 1):

a few years late but maybe this will help someone else...

Use a `using static` directive to reference the static class: ([introduced in C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static))

```
using static HelperTools;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DoWork();
    }
}

---------------- HelperTools.cs--------------------
class HelperTools
{
    public static void DoWork()
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only place you can call `DoWork` from without referencing the class name is within the class itself.  For instance, if you add a non-static method to `HelperTools`:

```
public void foo()
{
    DoWork();
}
```

You can call `DoWork` from within it, even though `foo()` is not static.

Comment: Close, but this answer is not quite accurate; the first sentence is wrong. It should read "The only place you can call DoWork without referencing the class name is within the *scope* of DoWork". Since DoWork is a public method of an internal class, you can use its unqualified name in the body of a derived class.